# How database can be designed to maintain and display master data supporting different languages (i18n)?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, internationalization

We have Spring MVC application with Hibernate used as DAO layer and MySql as database. This database has master tables for job title, skills, industry etc. Each master table have 2 columns(id, value). As of now, the value column in each master table has data in ENGLISH language. Going forward, we want the master tables to support different languages(i18n/internationalization) like french, Chinese, Portuguese etc. Secondly, we display this master data on UI as autocomplete drop down, depending on the alphabets entered by the user in the text field. For example:- if user types "ja" then values like "java, javac, javadci" etc. will be displayed in the drop down from master table using query which has "like" parameter in the where clause. What could be the best strategy or design which could solve this problem of maintaining and displaying master data with i18n support?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I would just add a value column for each supported language, and modify the requests to include the locale name in the column name. By example:

```
SELECT * FROM master WHERE valueEN LIKE 'ja';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM master WHERE valueFR LIKE 'ja';
```

Comment: How are you going to store master data belonging to each language? Will you choose to have a separate master table for each language? OR will you choose to add extra column in each master table for a new language ? Both the option do not look good, If we choose to have separate table then just imagine if there are 10 different master tables which should support 10 languages then I will have to add 10 X 10 = 100 tables. In case of second option, depending on the required no. of language support, no. of columns in each master table will go on increasing. I need something better.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to have mutliple masters, but to add a new column for each language. Why is adding columns a problem for you?

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that columns of a table will go on increasing as we go on adding new language support. Also using the language columns while querying the table will be clunky.